# How do I change the hostname of a Windows PC with batch or powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, networking, hostname

I want to change the hostname of a computer from Batch (a.k.a. Command Prompt) or Powershell.

Initially I started research into using the `wmic` command. But running `wmic /?` on Windows 10 21H1 indicates it is now deprecated.

[image]

Then I looked at `Get-WmiObject`. But when I run `man Get-WmiObject` in PowerShell, the description indicates it has been "superseded" by `Get-CimInstance`.

[image]

Using the old `Get-WmiObject` command you could change your own computer's hostname with `(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Rename("New-Hostname")`.

What is a non-deprecated way to change your own Windows computer's hostname using Batch or PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Theo for the tip.

The PowerShell command [Rename-Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-computer?view=powershell-7.1)

```
Rename-Computer "new-hostname"
```

Admin privileges and a computer restart are required.

The command warns you if the length of the hostname is longer than 15 characters.

Comment: Glad to have helped with that, although a bit strange that my comment has been wiped..?..

Comment: You can also add the `-Restart` option to the command, so it restarts immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The `batch-file` command...

```
NETDOM RENAMECOMPUTER "%ComputerName%" /Newname:"NewNameGoesHere" /FORCE
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple code if you want to use it

```
@echo off
set /p newname=The name of the new device:
wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" call rename name="%newname%"
```

Anyway, this is what you are looking for

```
wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" call rename name="newname"
```

Comment: That may work, but the question shows that wmic is deprecated and the point was to get away from using it or other deprecated commands.